# Base64 Image конфликтует с остальным HTML

Tags: php, html, base64

У меня есть изображения base64. Я  шифрую и потом дешифровываю эти изображения. После дешифровки со всеми base64 изображениями получаеться так, что они "проглатывают" остальной HTML код. Как мне это исправить? Делаю ли я все правильно? Надо хранить base64 изображения отдельно?

Пример нормального кода изображения:

```
<img class="rg_ic rg_i" id="rA1d9HtE2ClTlM:" jsaction="load:str.tbn" alt="Картинки по запросу kot" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
```

Пример кода с "проглоченным" кодом HTML:

```
<img class="rg_ic rg_i" id="rA1d9HtE2ClTlM:" jsaction="load:str.tbn" alt="Картинки по запросу kot" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxMT&lt;/td&gt;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;  &lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&lt;span id=p0&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&lt;div id='content'&gt;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&lt;table&gt;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9; &lt;tr&gt;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;  &lt;td width='10%'&gt;&lt;img width=100vw src='data/img/4.png'&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;  &lt;td width='80%'&gt;&lt;h4&gt;Alexander (olexander) Kornienko&lt;/h4&gt;&lt;hr&gt;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;  &lt;h4&gt;2018.06.14 22:48:03&lt;/h4&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9; &lt;/tr&gt;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9; &lt;tr&gt;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;  &lt;td colspan=2&gt;&lt;p&gt;Тест&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;img class=" irc_mi"="" width="474" height="474">
```

Код сам не генерирую. Генерирует Quill (WYSIWYG editor). Шифрую с помощью `AES-256-CFB1`. Вот функции:

```
openssl_encrypt($message, "AES-256-CFB1", $hash, true, "fYkj34FShjf7Smo9");
openssl_decrypt($message, "AES-256-CFB1", $hash, true, "fYkj34FShjf7Smo9");
```

Я использую эту схему для сохранения постов. А картинка не выводиься из-за "проглоченного" HTML.

MAX, картинки не содержат мусорный HTML. Это конструкция моего сайта. А шифрую я картинки вместе со всем остальным так как это (Quill) редактор текста в основе.

Что-то не так именно с base64, так как картинки где просто указан линк на стронний ресурс работают.

Comment: base64 это строка, конфликтовать она сама по себе не может. Добавьте в вопрос ваш код генерации того тега img с base64

Comment: Чем шифруете и дешифруете?

Comment: А в чем вообще смысл таких манипуляций? Если в конечном счете тому кому нужна будет картинка все равно ее получит?

Comment: У вас данные картинки содержат какой-то «мусорный» html, то есть это не base64-кодирование. То есть для картинок не нужно дополнительное шифорование, только кодирование base64.